# Unable to locate package google-drive-ocamlfuse , suddenly stopped working

Tags: google-drive-api, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I have been using colab lately and till now I used google-drive-ocamlfuse to link my project to my drive but not it is unable to load package.

```
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/google-drive-ocamlfuse-beta
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
```

got referenced form here
https://medium.com/@burakteke/tutorial-on-using-google-colab-for-kaggle-competition-620393c22821

till yesterday it was working like a charm but today it suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work fine as per https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/issues/493#issuecomment-422380636

Change the build between `amd64`, `arm64`, `armhf`, `i386` from https://launchpad.net/~alessandro-strada/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!wget https://launchpad.net/~alessandro-strada/+archive/ubuntu/google-drive-ocamlfuse-beta/+build/15331130/+files/google-drive-ocamlfuse_0.7.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
!dpkg -i google-drive-ocamlfuse_0.7.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
!apt-get install -f
!apt-get -y install -qq fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler fix is to use the built-in Drive FUSE client:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

More details:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA