# Unable to Generate creds for the Drive FUSE library

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I decide to use colab and google-drive-ocamlfuse to link my project to my drive, after reading a blog, the reference is herehttp://medium.com/@burakteke/tutorial-on-using-google-colab-for-kaggle-competition-620393c22821

I have fiexed its first part to install fuse after reading the answer from here [Unable to locate package google-drive-ocamlfuse , suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385655/unable-to-locate-package-google-drive-ocamlfuse-suddenly-stopped-working)

when I am trying to do the third part:

```
# Generate creds for the Drive FUSE library.
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

it just keep running, and I found no anwer from anywhere... please see the pic here[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than debugging this third-party wrapper, it's simpler to use the built-in Drive FUSE client:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then, your files will be available, and you can interact with them in the built-in file browser.

[image]