# Having trouble with google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I tried to mount google drive on google colab I got this error. Any help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qozX.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to locate package google-drive-ocamlfuse , suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385655/unable-to-locate-package-google-drive-ocamlfuse-suddenly-stopped-working)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question, as this will help the community understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?:

```
from google.colab import drive
  drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

  with open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/hello.npy", 'wb') as outfile:
      np.save(outfile, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

After execute this code you will be asked for permission to give drive access. 
After that you will be able to browse your drive directory by following commands:

```
cd drive      //Change directory to drive folder
cd My Drive   //Change directory to your Google Drive folder
ls            //List of drive folder
```